# Java - Android SQLite No Such Table Exists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm creating an app that wil query a database, however, the tables cannot be detected.

I have followed the steps indicated in this blog: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I made the android_metadata table, copied it to the assets folder, and created the DataBaseHelper Class as shown below:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String MedicalStaff = null;
private static final String Patients = null;

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.angelo.thesis/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "androidHospital";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            //throw new Error("Error copying database");
            System.out.println("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

This database helper is then initialized using:

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
```

And in the `onCreate` method:

```
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        System.out.println("Database Created!");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unable to create database");
    }


    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        System.out.println("Database Opened!");
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unable to open database");
    }
```

The try-catch statements work, the LogCat displays Created and Opened messages.

Then the query is made by this function:
String input is a user input, a number that is used to look for the person corresponding to that number.

```
public String searchStaff(DataBaseHelper myDB, String input){

    System.out.println("searchStaff entered");

    String data = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();

    //int myNum = Integer.parseInt(input);

    try{
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM MedicalStaff WHERE _id =" + input, null);

    }   
    catch(Exception e){
    }

    if( cursor != null ){
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LastName")) + " " +
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));   
        cursor.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Data: " + data);
    return data;

}
```

However, the data displayed becomes `null` and Log Cat tells me that the table `MedicalStaff` does not exist.

I have a feeling I'm missing out on something very basic in here. 
Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line of code

`` `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null); ``

to

`DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);`

This is because you creating an Databasehelper object with null. So create with specified context.

Comment: @Razgriz have you checked whether database is created with that table in your sqlite database browser. Make sure you not initialised the database object twice.

Comment: Yes it was created. I also tried to query the other table but it can't seem to find it.

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the table name you created with `MedicalStaff`. Can you update the coding for table creation.

Comment: I think I did something wrong with the database creation. I tried adding a different database and searching that and it worked.

Comment: Oh. Superb. If you find my answer helped you then accept it as answer. So others will know you got answer. Happy coding

Comment: Though looking at it, I wonder why it does not work. It looks like it was created properly. http://i47.tinypic.com/2i9k19g.png

Comment: Mmm. Its really wired. Some times we have to do non-logical thing to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

I think Database created successfully.but Table creation not done. Please check..

Comment: @Razgiz Please read  Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite

Comment: Does this also work for databased created by SQLite Database Browser? The link you gave seems to cover databased created by android applications.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
```

to

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
```

If you initialize DataBaseHelper passing null as parameter then, Database Helper will not get the Context and will result unexpected behaviour as you are facing now. So Change your code as above and give try. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`new DataBaseHelper(null);` doesn't look good. You should initialize it with a valid context